# How to run swagger-codegen for OpenAPI 3.0.0

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen, openapi

looks like official [swagger](/questions/tagged/swagger) for [openapi](/questions/tagged/openapi) specification V3 support is near release https://blog.readme.io/an-example-filled-guide-to-swagger-3-2/, and the swagger-codegen has 3.0.0 support developed and passing some level of testing https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen on the `3.0.0` branch

I have a swagger spec (generated from my existing 2.0 spec via https://github.com/mermade/swagger2openapi, output looks good)

Is there an easy way to run the swagger-codegen without having to package the jar myself?

- this is the single result i found: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ but running that seems to be broken (from the output, possibly actually running 2.0 not 3.0.0?):

> [main] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from /input/myspec.openapi3.json
>       [main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.ignore.CodegenIgnoreProcessor - No .swagger-codegen-ignore file found.
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config!
>           at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:685)
>           at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:285)
>           at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)

It looks like the swagger-codegen repo has a somewhat supported way to run a docker container *after* you build; I'm just hoping/guessing there is a supported way to do this without needing to compile locally, as I need to set this up in several places.

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/bentheadset/bentheadset-swagger-codegen-3.0.0/ pulls the .jar published in the link above ( https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ )

Comment: OpenAPI 3.0 support is being worked on. Please refer to the branch (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/3.0.0_enhancements) for progress.

Comment: @WilliamCheng Your link has gone dead.

Comment: @tchrist thanks for reporting the broken link. I'm no longer involved in Swagger Codegen. Please refer to my answer below for more information.

Comment: Please see this slightly newer question re using the swagger codegen maven plugin on an OpenAPI 3.0 spec bcos it has working answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616529/swagger-codegen-with-maven-plugin-for-openapi-3-0

Answer (score 16):

[OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech) (found by top contributors of Swagger Codegen) supports both OpenAPI specification v2 and v3.

You can use the [docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/), [Java JAR (SNAPSHOT)](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/), [Brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openapi-generator) or [npm](https://npmjs.com/package/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli) to give it a try.

For more information about OpenAPI Generator, please refer to the project's [README](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator)

If you need any help, please [open an issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new) and we'll look into it.

UPDATE: 1st stable version 3.0.0 has been released: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/releases/tag/v3.0.0

Answer (score 3):

Swagger-codegen 3.0.0 snapshots now include a limited number of targets for code generation from OpenAPI 3.0 definitions. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/6598#issuecomment-333428808

There is an alternative experimental implementation of the codegen engine, using the original swagger-codegen 2.x templates, written in Node.js: https://github.com/mermade/openapi-codegen - if your language is not yet supported, a config file just needs to be created for it mapping the template files to outputs.