# How to generate ASP.NET Core 2 controllers from OpenAPI 3.0 schema?

Tags: asp.net-core, code-generation, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I have an OpenAPI 3.0 schema YAML document that defines some API endpoints with all the required parameters and responses.

Now, I'd like to generate some boilerplate server-side code: the controllers and their methods. My API will be written using ASP.NET Core 2. So, is it possible to use some kind of generators or should I do it manually?

P.S. I know that I can generate the client-side code, but I don't need it right now...

Comment: OAS3 support in Swagger-Codegen is in progress - but the ASP.NET codegen is currently not available. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/6598#issuecomment-360780224

Comment: Related: [How to run swagger-codegen for openapi 3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45717099/113116)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech), which is a community-driven version of Swagger Codegen and supports both OpenAPI spec v2, v3.

For more information on why we (top contributors) forked it, please refer to the [Q&A](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/qna.md)

If you've docker installed, you can easily try it with the following command

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
    -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openapitools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/petstore.yaml \
    -g aspnetcore \
    -o /local/out/aspnetcore
```

For any question or feedback, please open a ticket via https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new

Comment: wooow. It's amazing! Thanks

Comment: As we learned the hard way, OpenAPI Generator's C# code generation is very limited and lacks proper support for a lot of OpenAPI features.  In particular OneOf/AllOf/AnyOf aren't officially supported and are quite finicky unless you bring your own models or customize the templates.

Comment: `csharp` supports allOf, anyOf and oneOf. Which version of OpenAPI Generator are you using? The latest is v7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I think there exist some tools for NSwag that generate server-side code.
[image]

src: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

The tool NSwagStudio has also an option for the controller generation
[image]