# Swagger Codegen (with maven plugin) for OpenAPI 3.0

Tags: maven, swagger, swagger-codegen, openapi, openapi-generator

I want to use Swagger Codegen for OpenAPI 3.0 YAML file. And I see [Swagger Codegen 3.0.0-rc0](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases/tag/v3.0.0-rc0) is available. But when I try to use that I run into issues. Following are the details:

My `pom.xml` file with swagger-codegen plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-rc0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <inputSpec>${basedir}/src/main/resources/mySpec.yaml</inputSpec>
        <output>target/generated-sources</output>
        <language>spring</language>
        <generateApis>false</generateApis>
        <modelPackage>com.kj.model</modelPackage>
        <apiPackage>com.kj</apiPackage>
        <configOptions>
          <sourceFolder>swagger</sourceFolder>
          <library>spring-mvc</library>
          <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
          <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
          <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
          <java8>true</java8>
        </configOptions>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

With the above plugin when I run the maven build, I got this `ServiceConfigurationError`, here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.swagger.codegen.CodegenConfig: Provider io.swagger.codegen.languages.java.JavaClientCodegen not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at io.swagger.codegen.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:19)
    at io.swagger.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:392)
    at io.swagger.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute(CodeGenMojo.java:512)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
```

In order to fix this I added `swagger-codegen-generators` dependency **within the maven plugin** section of pom file:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-generators</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So with this earlier mentioned issue got resolved but now I see this NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.swagger.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen.preprocessOpenAPI(SpringCodegen.java:429)
    at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.configureGeneratorProperties(DefaultGenerator.java:199)
    at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:716)
    at io.swagger.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute(CodeGenMojo.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
```

As you would have noted already that I am using `<language>spring</language>` and `<library>spring-mvc</library>`. Please let me know if codegen has worked for someone for 3.0.0-rc0 with these configurations.

**Note:** I looked at this old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45717099/948268) which is similar but at that time `3.0.0-rc0` was not available.

Comment: You could create an issue on the repository, since this is a release candidate and point out to the line in question https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/v3.0.0-rc0/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages/SpringCodegen.java#L429

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To use Swagger Codegen with Maven plug-in for OpenAPI 3.0.0 spec, you may consider using [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech) instead (which is a community-driven version of Swagger Codegen).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Ref: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator#12---artifacts-on-maven-central

(please refer to the [Q&A](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/qna.md) on why we forked Swagger Codegen)

Comment: As of '22 this still doesn't support a number of openapi 3 spec features such as "oneOf".

Comment: Does it support now?

Answer (score 20):

The v3 swagger codegen maven plugin released April 2019 generates working Java client libraries from an OpenAPI 3.0 spec, I'm using this Maven pom.xml plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8</version>
    <executions>
    ..
```

All the rest of the configuration and configOptions entries are unchanged from version 2.4.5. I had to replace the old annotation dependency with the following so the client code would compile:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Per request from @kozla13 below I added a complete POM example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- This groupId will NOT allow deployment in LF -->
    <groupId>org.example.swaggerapi.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-client</artifactId>
    <name>Example</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <client.base.package.name>org.example.so</client.base.package.name>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Required for Java 9 and later -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HTTP client: Spring RestTemplate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON processing: jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- This 2019 version is required for OpenAPI 3 -->
                <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/ric-plt-a1/a1/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <packageName>${client.base.package.name}</packageName>
                            <modelPackage>${client.base.package.name}.model</modelPackage>
                            <apiPackage>${client.base.package.name}.api</apiPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>${client.base.package.name}.invoker</invokerPackage>
                            <configOptions>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                <artifactVersion>${project.version}</artifactVersion>
                                <library>resttemplate</library>
                                <java8>true</java8>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <licenseName>Apache 2.0</licenseName>
                                <licenseUrl>https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</licenseUrl>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: do you habe full example

Comment: @kozla13 are you asking for a full pom.xml example, or a full OpenAPI 3.0 spec example?

Comment: full pom.xml example

Comment: why do we need invokerPackage?

Comment: @BilboBaggins the invokerPackage receives the ApiClient class, which carries config like the remote host/port and is accepted by the constructor of all API classes in the api package.

Comment: I am getting io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty does not exist